# how to hide uicollectionview on a ViewController using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, viewcontroller

I have a simple ViewController which has a 2 buttons names "Files" and "Folders". Also i have placed two uiCollectionView.

When I tap "Files" button it should hide one of the uiCollectionView at runtime and when I tap "Folders" it should do same for other uiCollectionView. Is there any property or method to achieve the same.

how can i do this using swift ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `.hidden` property on any of your views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide:

```
collectionView.hidden = true
```

To show:

```
collectionView.hidden = false
```

If you want to animate this, you can fade in and fade out.

Fade out:

```
self.collectionView.alpa = 1
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, {
    self.collectionView.alpha = 0
})
```

Fade in:

```
self.collectionView.alpa = 0
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, {
    self.collectionView.alpha = 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`collectionView.alpha = 0` I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve UI wise, but there are probably better solutions to stacking collection views.

`collectionView.hidden = true` also achieves the same thing